# online database of clever phrases

Tags: tools, word-choice, poetry

Is there a website that has a collection of clever or poetic phrases or expressions that one can search or browse through.  What about a book?  I used to have a book like this but I lost it.  It had entries like...

```
Rooted in prejudice
Pursued in Leisure
Ending in smoke
etc...
```

Iv'e been searching google without any luck.

Comment: Are you looking for a source that lists cliches?

Comment: I'm looking for future cliches that haven't been discovered yet.  (I lack original thought )

Comment: @tave Read Shakespeare's plays: They're full of clichés. It's amazing how that man took all those clichés and managed to string them together to make a coherent story.

Comment: Note that OP wants clever **phrases**, not clever **quotes**.

Comment: @user185383: You could search for idioms.  That might help.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. There's a very famous book: Bartlett's Familiar Quotations. e.g. [http://www.amazon.com/Bartletts-Familiar-Quotations-Geoffrey-OBrien/dp/0316017590/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1430161531&sr=8-1&keywords=bartlets+familiar+quotations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316017590)

I've seen quite a few websites of clever quips and quotes. For example, brainyquote.com, quotationspage.com, etc. Just google for "quotes" and you should get a ton of them.

Comment: not looking for quotes.

Comment: What do you mean, then, when you say that you are looking for "clever phrases", but not "clever quotes"? If someone said or wrote a phrase or sentence, and it's clever, we call it a "quote". Or are you thinking perhaps of phrases too short to be considered a quote, just brief figures of speech or idioms?